# Flutter - ExpansionTitle

Tags: flutter

Good morning, everyone! I'm encountering an issue with the `ExpansionTile` regarding spacing. Here's my code:

```
  return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
        child: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: ExpansionTile(
              initiallyExpanded: initiallyExpanded(indiceDaLista),
              onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                atualizaStatus(value);
              },
              iconColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              collapsedIconColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              title: AutoSizeText(
                titulo,
                style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: AppColors.pAzul,
                ),
                softWrap: true,
                maxLines: 3,
              ),
              subtitle: subTitulo == "" || subTitulo == null
                  ? null
                  : Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          subTitulo,
                          style: AppEstilosTexto.bodyCinzaW300,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          subTitulo,
                          style: AppEstilosTexto.bodyCinzaW300,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppColors.cBranco,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: AppColors.cBranco,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
                      bottom: Radius.circular(25),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15,
                      bottom: 10,
                      right: 15,
                    ),
                    // child: BodyDetalhesDoCard(
                    //   listaDiciplinas: listaDiciplinas,
                    //   listaModulos: listaDeConhecimentos.,
                    //   model: model,
                    //   crPeriodo: crPeriodo,
                    // ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.cBranco,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

How is the code above:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4akl.png)

and how do I leave the subtitle below the list icon
image expected result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuy6r.png)

I'm trying to put the subtitle inside a Row but it still has white space below the ExpansionTile icon

Comment: what do you want I could not understand it?

Comment: I would like the row text to be below the list icon https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuy6r.png